# Raspberry pi 3B+ bluetooth yes/no

Tags: bluetooth

I hope someone can help me with this, as it's driving me crazy!

I have connected mmy wife's and my mobile/cell phone via bluetooth to the rpi.

So far so good.

However, when I run bluetoothctl I notice that it constantly connects and disconnects.

Why?

```
pi@chrysler:/var/www/html/scripts $ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Device 78:02:F8:1E:xx:yy Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 60:AB:67:56:yy:xx Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 78:02:F8:1E:xx:yy Connected: no
[CHG] Device 60:AB:67:56:yy:xx Connected: no
[CHG] Device 78:02:F8:1E:xx:yy Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 60:AB:67:56:yy:xx Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 78:02:F8:1E:xx:yy Connected: no
[CHG] Device 60:AB:67:56:yy:xx Connected: no
[CHG] Device 60:AB:67:56:yy:xx Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 60:AB:67:56:yy:xx Connected: no
[CHG] Device 78:02:F8:1E:xx:yy Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 78:02:F8:1E:xx:yy Connected: no
[CHG] Device 60:AB:67:56:yy:xx Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 60:AB:67:56:yy:xx Connected: no
[CHG] Device 78:02:F8:1E:xx:yy Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 78:02:F8:1E:xx:yy Connected: no
[CHG] Device 60:AB:67:56:yy:xx Connected: yes
...
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Inside of `bluetoothctl`, issue the command `show` and it will tell you about the Raspberry Pi, including what UUIDs (services) it supports. The command `info 78:02:F8:1E:xx:yy` and `info 60:AB:67:56:yy:xx` will say about the UUIDs (services) are on the mobile phones.

Typically when you see the connecting and disconnecting like this it is because there is not compatible services on both ends of the Bluetooth link.  What is it you are wanting the Bluetooth to do when it is connect? Are those UUIDs there on both phone and the RPi?

To get more detailed debug information, have `sudo btmon` running in another terminal.

Comment: Thanks ukBaz. But how do I see the UUIDS on my android mobile phone?

Comment: I am assuming that `60:AB:67:56:yy:xx` is the address of one of the phones. If that is correct then the `info 60:AB:67:56:yy:xx` should give you that information. The key concept, is what service/functionality is your RPi providing that the phone wants to connect to? Audio? Serial? Sensors?

Comment: I am building a vehicle tracker. The rpi is gathering long/lat data and storing it. I would like to send the data via bluetooth to the phone which in turn is connected to the internet, so that this data reaches my server at home. It all kind of works, but does not seem totally reliable. I would like to check the bluetooth connection periodically and only send data if the connection is there. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It kind of makes sense. However, there is not a specific question (or details of what you have implemented) for me to respond to.

Comment: I think I am getting closer on finding my problem. It may have something to do with a bash script that I have. Will report back....